# Transform delimited values with hierarchy levels to individual assignments

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a list of delimited users and their assigned levels in a hierarchy.  I'd like to have each user on its own row, but maintain the levels assigned to the original.

This is what I start with:

| User | Level 1 |
| --- | --- |
| User1@demo.com;User2@demo.com;User3@demo.com | Region 1 |

This is what I'd like to end with:

| User | Level 1 |
| --- | --- |
| User1@demo.com | Region 1 |
| User2@demo.com | Region 1 |
| User3@demo.com | Region 1 |

I have hundreds of rows and multiple levels of the hierarchy, so just a text to columns and c/p is too time consuming.

I'd prefer a vba-free solution if possible.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please note that superuser.com is not a free script/code/homework writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code/calculations you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [Ask].

Comment: All I've been able to do so far is to move the text to columns, then transpose those cells from horizontal to vertical. It's just a lot of copy and paste, which is why I'm seeking help.  I don't know what else to try, or if there's anything to do.

Comment: Look into Power Pivot, it is the best tool for this.

Comment: @Scott Craner, will PowerPivot work if there are multiple user in a single cell delimited by semicolons?

Comment: Yes, you can split and transpose the cell value and expand the other cells into the new rows.  I am not sure how to do it, because I prefer sql databases to do this kind of thing. But I have seen many examples on StackOverflow doing this exact thing. @Brian

Comment: @Joshua Ball, do you still need a solution. I have a solution but it will take a little bit of time to put into tutorial format. Also, if I take the time to do this, after you verify it is a solution, will you mark is as being an answer?

Comment: @Brian If you have a solution that meets the requirements, ie no VBA and can expand to the `hundreds of rows and multiple levels of the hierarchy` then put it as an answer.  Even if the OP does not mark it as correct you may still help others in the future and get upvotes.  The answer are not just for the OP but those who have similar questions in the future.

Comment: I'd be happy to mark as the answer if it fulfills the need.

Comment: To let someone specific know you are responding, use the `@` in front of their name ie: @Brian

Answer (score 2):

With Office 365:

```
=LET(
    us,A2:A201,
    hr,B2:D201,
    ttl,A1:D1,
    VSTACK(ttl,DROP(REDUCE("",us&"|"&BYROW(hr,LAMBDA(z,TEXTJOIN("{",FALSE,z))),LAMBDA(a,b,LET(c,TEXTAFTER(b,"|"),VSTACK(a,HSTACK(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTBEFORE(b,"|"),,";"),DROP(TEXTSPLIT(REPT(c&"}",ROWS(TEXTSPLIT(b,,";"))),"{","}"),-1)))))),1)))
```

Basically, it will split the text on the `;` in the `us`(User) range.  Then it Repeats the values by row in the `hr`(hierarchy) range.  Then it stacks them horizontally.

The REDUCE will then stack each row's output vertically.  Finally we stack on the `ttl`(title) range.

[image]

Comment: I wish I could comment on your method but it is over my head. It appears however to be quite impressive. I would love to have access to the source data that led to your results so I could trace its work in Excel.

Answer (score 1):

1. Select the data range and go to the `INSERT` menu

[image]

2. Select `TABLE` and check/uncheck `My Table Has Headers` as is appropriate.

[image]

3. Select your data range, go to `DATA` menu and click `From Table/Range`

[image]

4. In `Power Query Editor`, select `column1`, click on `Split Column`, and click on `By Delimiter`.

[image]

5. Enter `;` as your custom delimiter and click `okay`.

[image]

6. Select `Column2` then dropdown `Unpivot Columns` and then select `Unpivot Other Columns`.

[image]

7. Select the `Attribute` column.

[image]

8. Right click on column and select `Remove`

[image]

9. From the `HOME` menu, click `Close and Load`

[image]